# IDLE is not opening python3.8

Tags: python-idle, python-3.8

I installed Python3.8 on a LINUX Mint OS in the terminal, but IDLE still opens Python version 3.6.9. How do I get IDLE to open Python 3.8.
I can open Python 3.8 from the terminal, but when I open IDLE it opens Python version 3.6.9

Comment: At least on windows, you will have a separate IDLE installation for each python version

Comment: I'm using Linux

Comment: In a terminal, enter "python -m idlelib", where 'python' is the python one wants to run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
python3.8 C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw
```